# How to read and write .ini files using boost library

Tags: c++, boost, ini

How to read and write (or modify) .ini files using boost library?

Comment: I need not only parse the .ini file, I also need to modify its values

Comment: Is your question about regular expressions or which `boost` function to use?

Comment: @yosoy89: You can also modify the values with `<boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `Boost.PropertyTree` you can read and update the tree, then write to a file (see `load` and `save` functions.

Have a look at [How to access data in property tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/accessing.html).
You can definitely add new property or update existing one.
It mentiones that there's `erase` on container as well so you should be able to delete existing value. Example from `boost` (link above):

```
ptree pt;
pt.put("a.path.to.float.value", 3.14f);
// Overwrites the value
pt.put("a.path.to.float.value", 2.72f);
// Adds a second node with the new value.
pt.add("a.path.to.float.value", 3.14f);
```

I would assume you would then write updated tree into a file, either new one or overwrite existing one.

**EDIT :**
For ini file it does specific checks.

The above example if you try to save to ini with ini_parser you get:

1. ptree is too deep
2. duplicate key

With that fixed here is an example code that writes ini file, I've updated a value of existing key then added a new key:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

void save(const std::string &filename)
{
   using boost::property_tree::ptree;

//   pt.put("a.path.to.float.value", 3.14f);
//   pt.put("a.path.to.float.value", 2.72f);
//   pt.add("a.path.to.float.value", 3.14f);

   ptree pt;
   pt.put("a.value", 3.14f);
   // Overwrites the value
   pt.put("a.value", 2.72f);
   // Adds a second node with the new value.
   pt.add("a.bvalue", 3.14f);

   write_ini( filename, pt );
}

int main()
{
    std::string f( "test.ini" );
    save( f );
}
```

the `test.ini` file:

```
[a]
value=2.72
bvalue=3.14
```

Feel free to experiment.

Comment: when you say:
pt.put("a.path.to.float.value",3.14f);
how it is represented in a .ini file? Remember .ini files are in the form [Elements] Elem1=Value1 ...

Comment: I'd give it a try, see updated answer, I've added example code for ini file

Comment: Can boost handle INI files with utf8 encoding?

Comment: @stefanB Please add the prefix `boost::property_tree::` to your call to `write_ini` - it took me 20 minutes to figure this out. I would do it myself, but edits like this usually get rejected.